# Find $\Delta CEH$ in terms of $\Delta DEH$, $\Delta BEH$ and $\Delta BCH$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have been asked to do the following question:

> In the following picture, Line BH is trapezium ABCD's height. Line AC connects two opposite corners, and E is a point on AC. If $\Delta DEH$, $\Delta BEH$, and $\Delta BCH$ is $a$, $b$, and $c$, find $\Delta CEH$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

[image]
All that I know is that $\Delta BEH$ and $\Delta BCH$ have a positive correlation with $\Delta CEH$. How do I move on from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $[ABC]$ be a symbol for the area of $\triangle ABC$. Then it's obvious that:

$$[BEC] + [CEH] = [BEH] + [BHC]$$

Now we'll use the fact that if two triangles have the same attitude then the ratio of their areas is the ratio of the sides perpendicular to the attitude. So:

$$[BEC] = \frac{CE}{AC} [ABC] = \frac{CE}{AC} [BAH] = \frac{CE}{AC} [DAH] = \frac{CE}{AC} \times \frac{DH}{DC} [DAC] = \frac{DH}{HC} [DEC] = [DEH]$$

Therefore we have:

$$[CEH] = [BEH] + [BHC] - [BEC] = [BEH] + [BHC] - [DEH] = b+c-a$$

Comment: Why $AD\perp DC$? I think it's not given.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I took the freedom to assume that from the picture. Anyway if that's not the case I doubt that's the ratio can be expressed purely by the means of $a,b,c$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg In fact we have $[CEH] = \frac{[BHC]}{DH \cdot HB} [DEH]$. $DH, HB$ are constant, but I don't that's what the OP needs

Comment: Yes, you are right. Without your assuming  it's impossible.